# Assigning number to column with condition

Tags: r

Assuming I have a df,

```
df = data.frame(matrix(rnorm(20), nrow=10))
df$group <- rep(NA,nrow(df)) # add one col
```

I want to randomly assign number 1 and 2 to `df$group` column to each row.

The percentage of number 1 is 60%, and 2 is 40% in this column.

But the order of data frame will not be changed by group column.

```
     X1         X2           group
1   0.74285307  1.7198207    1
2  -0.68202611  0.2978920    2
3  -0.48945803  0.3789607    1
4  -1.67500642 -0.5613542    1
5   0.81639247  0.3990585    2
6   0.43318010 -0.6742523    2
7   0.72981285  0.4524986    1
8   0.49378867  3.2580579    1
9   0.00837279  1.2755910    1
10 -2.42784153  0.9085665    2
```

How can I do it in elegant way using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sample()` to randomly choose numbers with weights. If you want the number on average to have a particular distribution you can use

```
df$group <- sample(1:2, nrow(df), replace=T, prob=c(.6, .4))
```

If you need it to be "exact", you would use

```
num1 <- round(nrow(df)*.6, 0)
df$group <- sample(c(rep(1, num1), rep(2, nrow(df)-num1)))
```

Comment: Maybe `replace=TRUE` would be safer.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/rQzFq       why it shows 9 number 1 and only 1 number 2 when I try 0.8 and 0.2 in the prob?

Comment: @BigSecret Well, it randomly samples from the distribution so any given observation may be different. Do you want it to be exactly those proportions? What if it's not an integer count?

Comment: Thanks, I wish it could be exactly as I set up. And just simply round it?

Comment: @BigSecrect I updated my answer